# Как правильно организовать 2 способа аутентификации для одного метода swagger?

Tags: node.js, аутентификация, swagger, passport

В методе `Authentication` я хотел бы организовать базовую аутентификацию и по токену. Аутентификации по токену будет проверять валидность токена и возвращать его же вместе с данными, если все хорошо.

В swagger прописал

```
security:
 - Basic: []
 - JWT: []
```

Использовал swagger 2.0, сервер генерировал nodejs-server.
В методах использовалась библиотека passport.

Вот реализация этих методов в nodejs:

```
function Basic(req, def, scopes, callback) {
    const METHOD = 'Basic()';
    console.log('\n', FILE, METHOD);
    passport.authenticate('basic', {session: false}, function (err, data, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(FILE, METHOD, '\n', err);
            req.error = err;
        } else {
            if(data) console.log(FILE, METHOD, '\n', 'User Authentication');
            req.user = data.user;
        }
        callback();
    })(req, null, callback);
}

function JWT(req, def, scopes, callback) {
    const METHOD = 'JWT()';
    console.log('\n', FILE, METHOD);
    passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function (err, data, info) {
        req.roles = RolesReq.getAllRoles();
        if (err) {
            console.error(FILE, METHOD, '\n', err);
            req.error = err;
        } else {
            if(data) console.log(FILE, METHOD, '\n', 'User Authentication');
            req.user = data.user;
        }
        callback();
    })(req, null, callback);
}

module.exports = {
    Basic: Basic,
    JWT: JWT
};
```

А вот подключение этих аутентификации в файле index.js:

```
// Initialize the Swagger middleware
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {

    // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
    appConnect.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());

    appConnect.use(middleware.swaggerSecurity({
        //manage token function in the 'auth' module
        Basic: secHandlers.Basic,
        JWT: secHandlers.JWT
    }));

    ...

    // Start the server
    http.createServer(appConnect).listen(serverPort, function () {
        console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
        console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
    });

});
```

Я передал в header либо данные базовой авторизации, либо токен JWT и ожидал, что сработает только 1 метод или другой. Вместо этого сработало оба метода и оба вернули null. То есть не было ни ошибки, ни авторизация не прошла.

По отдельности работают нормально. Если кто-нибудь делал подобное напишите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело было в лишнем дефисе.

Чтобы срабатывал только 1 из методов в Swagger в моем случае я поменял

```
security:
 - Basic: []
 - JWT: []
```

На

```
security:
 - Basic: []
   JWT: []
```

Теперь работает либо JWT, либо Basic.